# Issue Deploying Angular App to Azure Web Apps Angular 9

Tags: angular, azure-devops, azure-webapps

I have an angular app. 
here is part of the package.json

```
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "dist/index.html",
  "files": [ "dist/" ],
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-prod": "ng build --prod"
  },
```

It contains a web.config under the src folder

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed" />
      <rewrite>
        <rules>
          <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^(.*)$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
              <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" pattern="" ignoreCase="false" />
            </conditions>
            <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" appendQueryString="true"/>
          </rule>
        </rules>
      </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

In my Angular.json i add it under assets

```
    "assets": [
      "src/favicon.ico",
      "src/assets",
      "src/web.config"
    ],
```

i have the following steps in azure devops 
[image]

[image]
I have set up a virtual directory in my azre web app
[image]

this is the error i get 
[image]

Comment: Where is the `web.config` file in your `dist` folder when you run a build?

Comment: in the Source code the web.config is under src folder, In the artifact produced from the dist/AngularApp/web.config so one folder path up from the package.json which is under the dist folder directly

Comment: So just to be clear, your output folder looks a little bit like: `/dist/prod/web.config`, `/dist/prod/index.html`, etc?

Comment: i found the issue it was the virtual directory path was incorrect, thanks for your help though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue was self inflicted. My Virtual Directory path was missing the one level the \dist

It was set to site\wwwroot\package\AngularApp instead of site\wwwroot\package\dist\AngularApp

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, would you please accept your solution as the answer? So it would be helpful for other members who get the same issue to find the solution easily. Have a nice day:)